# Missing custom product attribute value in getData()

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

I have created a multiselect catalogue product attribute labelled **dangerous** (attribute ID: 1202) which should work exactly like an existing custom attribute **sport** (attribute ID: 1200).

The attribute is set up with the following options:

- **Scope**: Global
- **Use In Layered Navigation**: Filterable (with results)
- **Used in Product Listing**: Yes

My new **dangerous** attribute shows up properly in the product edit form in a multiselect dropdown. When I select options and save the product I can see the database getting updated.

The only problem I have is that I can't seem to get the **dangerous** attribute value via the **getData()** method.

`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(494643)->getData()` returns

```
Array (
    ...
    [supplier_warehouse] => United Kingdom
    [sport] => 4000
    [dangerous] =>
    [meta_keyword] => Nike Livestrong, Summer Cap (Black), Black, Headwear 
    ...
)
```

and both `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(494643)->getDangerous()` and `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(494643)->getData('dangerous')` return `null`.

On the other hand, this query:

```
SELECT
    cpe.entity_id AS product_id,
    cpev_sport.value AS sport,
    cpev_dangerous.value AS dangerous
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev_sport
ON cpev_sport.attribute_id = 1202
AND cpe.entity_id = cpev_sport.entity_id

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev_dangerous
ON cpev_dangerous.attribute_id = 1200
AND cpe.entity_id = cpev_dangerous.entity_id

WHERE cpe.entity_id = 494643
```

returns

```
+------------+-------+-----------+
| product_id | sport | dangerous |
+------------+-------+-----------+
|     494643 | 4000  | 4087      |
+------------+-------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Am I missing something obvious? Please note that I tried reindexing and clearing all types of cache, in vain so far.

**EDIT:** Additional info
I am using multi-store indeed but these attributes have a global scope (store ID: 0).
I have tried reindexing and clearing cache.

Comment: Are re indexing  from admin???

Comment: are you used multi store

Comment: are you using flat tables for products?

Comment: and how did you add your products, manually or via import?

Comment: Yes, I do use flat tables for products. However, in the edit form, I believe that `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(494643)` doesn't read it from that table since it isn't a collection. Unless I'm wrong?

Products were all imported via Magmi, but I'm unsure whether that would make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$product->getDangerous()` after flushing cache since often collections are cached.

Comment: I flushed all cache types I could think of but it didn't help, when I update the **sport** attribute value, it's updated immediately though.

The product is loaded directly from the model and not from a collection. I didn't get more successful with `$product->getDangerous()` which returns `null`